# Pull the code from branch to local and test in local, then revert the local to master without carrying any changes from branch

Tags: git

I run a Node.js app in AWS EC2. The source of this app are pulled from the master of a bitbucket server through git, then the modules are installed and the app is ran in the AWS EC2.

I want do some tests of new features, I created a development branch from the master on that bitbucket server, add some new modules into the development branch.

Expected result:
***In AWS EC2, I want to change the remote repository from master branch to development branch, pull the source from the development branch, then install the new modules and run the new app. After test, I want to change the remote repository back to master branch and roll back all source code to exactly the same as that on the master.***

Could you please tell how to achieve above expected result using git command?

Comment: This isn't so much a Git question as it is a question about how to do deployments to AWS.  If you have artifacts, then just deploy them as you wish.  Note that you might want to have separate environments for testing and production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

1. `git checkout -b dev` - create a local branch.
2. `git pull origin dev` - update with dev branch from server
3. `git push origin dev` - push changes (new modules etc.), the checkout to master (`git checkout master`)
4. `git branch -d dev` - delete local dev branch, now you only have master which is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your method. I create a file in local dev branch. But after I delete local dev branch. The file is still in local. I want to recovery local to the status before creating the local dev branch.

Comment: really strange that the file is still there, is your master changed or just the file is still present? if the latter then maybe `rm -rf` the file and be done with it.

Comment: To delete a branch first you will need to checkout from that branch to some other branch, git can't delete the same branch on which you are already checked out

Answer (score 1):

You just want to test the changes you have done on `development` branch I think, so you can do it like this:

```
git fetch origin
```

As you have already created and pushed the `development` branch on `bitbucket` you just need to do:

```
git checkout development
```

If the `development` branch already exists on the server you will have to do:

```
git pull origin development
```

or else `git` will already have the latest changes. Install the new modules do the test you want to perform and after everything is done you just need to do:

```
git checkout master
```

Back to `master` branch so you source code will be reverted back as in `master` branch. Deleting the `development` branch from the server is optional.

**Note:** Uninstall the newly installed modules manually if required

This is not a recommended approach to check your new changes directly on `production` server, you should have a different `test` enviornment to check the new changes.